# Why did Paul collect and deliver an offering for the Church in Jerusalem?

Tags: acts, romans, paul, galatians

Paul's collection for the Jerusalem church occupies significant portions of his letters (1 Cor 16:1–4; 2 Cor 8:1–9:15; Rom 15:14–32).  It is so important to Paul he is willing to face hostility (Romans 15:30-31) and is indeed arrested in Jerusalem in part because of it (Acts 24:17).  What compelled Paul to raise funds among his gentile converts for the poor in Jerusalem?  Why did he feel this money would be better spent on the poor in Jerusalem rather than on the poor gentiles surrounding the communities where he collected it?  What did he hope this offering would accomplish?

Comment: I don't think there's anything that says money was **not** given to the "poor gentiles surrounding the communities where he collected it." Rather, so much focus is on Jerusalem because it required more logistical coordination to send large sums of money to Jerusalem. Whereas, if Gentiles surrounding the local churches needed assistance, they only had to go to that local church. Also, during that time, there were few churches in Judea. Either most Christians had been exiled along with the Jews, or the non-believing Jews were persecuting the believing Jews. In such a case, bel. Jews needed help.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 But also see 2 Cor. 8:1-2

Comment: Interesting scripture @Soldarnal. Thank you.

Comment: You've answered why it might be mentioned over and above an offering to the surrounding gentile.  But I'm not assuming that money wasn't given to the poor gentiles.  A gift to Jewish Christian some 800 miles away in Jerusalem necessarily takes the money away from otherwise local purposes.  Why then did Paul think it important that they send such an offering to Jerusalem and not to poor Christians in another city, let say like Antioch?

Comment: No church was a stranger to persecution at this time, but it was especially severe and long lasting in Jerusalem. [Here](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%208&version=NIV) and [here](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2021:26-30&version=NIV). I think it is to be expected that wide spread poverty among the church would be one of the many side effects of this persecution.

Comment: And now the subject of a feature film: for info, ebook, and trailers, see the ["A Polite Bribe" website](http://apolitebribe.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, Paul sees his outreach to the Gentiles as a ministry to Israel (Romans 11:12-15).  God promised Abraham that in his seed all the nations (Gentiles) of the world would be blessed (Genesis 22:18; Galatians 3:15).  And Isaiah prophesied

> In the last days the mountain of the Lord’s temple will be established
>   as the highest of the mountains; it will be exalted above the hills,
>   and all nations will stream to it. (Isaiah 2:2)

Paul's understands his ministry and particularly this offering as a fulfillment of God's promises.  Through this offering the Gentiles are journeying to Jerusalem to worship the God of Israel and in so doing offering themselves as proof to the Jews that Jesus is the one Christians claim him to be.

In Galatians, the origins of the offering appears as a important bridge between Paul's Gentile ministry and Peter, James and John's ministry to the Jews.  To see this we need to understand the context in which the mention of an offering first appears.

Paul wrote Galatians to defend against Jewish Christians who taught that Gentile believers in Jesus needed to follow the traditions of the Jews. Paul is resolute in his hostility to such a doctrine, eternally condemning any who preach a message other than the one he delivered to them (Galatians 1:8-9). To give context to his opposition, Paul recounts his own history; his former zeal for these traditions, his conversion and his subsequent relationship with the Jerusalem church who are presumably the source of the present conflict.

Paul claims to initailly have been extremely zealous for the traditions of his fathers, alluding to God's commendation of Phineius who killed an Israelite man in the very act of fornicating with a Gentile woman (Numbers 25:1-8).  But a revelation of Jesus and Paul's call to the Gentiles changes all that.  Without consulting anyone (once again presumably leaders in Jerusalem), Paul journeys to Arabia (2:17) and possibly even Mt. Sinai (4:25).  Its only three years later that Paul briefly meets some of the apostles, Peter and James, in Jerusalem.  In all this Paul stresses that his message came from God and not from any man.

14 years pass before Paul feels compelled to consult with these leaders in Jerusalem again.  Paul presents the message he preaches among the Gentiles privately to them in the hope that they will see it from his point of view. Peter and James agree that they should go to the Jews and Paul should continue his outreach among the Gentiles.  The one thing they ask is that he "continue to remember the poor."

This last phrase, "continue to remember the poor," appears to refer specifically to the poor in Jerusalem. Paul gives ample evidence to a serious tension that existed between Jewish Christians in Jerusalem and his ministry among the Gentiles.  That this meeting and agreement occurred "in private" likewise suggests that Peter and James felt apprehensive in giving Paul the right hand of fellowship.  A financial offering from Paul and his Gentile converts would certainly help to smooth out any difficulty that might develop among the believers in Jerusalem.

There are also other reasons to see this phrase as a reference to the poor in Jerusalem.

1. James and Peter's request that Paul "***continue*** to remember the poor" indicates that this something Paul is already doing. If Galatians is written prior to the Jerusalem council (Acts 15), than this meeting occurred when Paul delivered aid from the church in Antioch to the famine starved church in Jerusalem (Acts 11:27-30).
2. Paul claims his offering for the Jersualem church is for "the poor among the saints in Jerusalem" (Romans 16:26).
3. His audience would presumably understand the shorthand reference since they themselves had been instructed about Paul's collection (1 Corinthians 16:1-2).

Paul's commitment to the poor in Jerusalem does not originate with Peter and James. It's an idea which appears to be fundamental to his understanding of his ministry among the Gentiles.  This can been seen in his letter to the Romans.

Scholars are apt to point out that Paul wrote to the Romans to prepare for a further missionary trip to spain (Romans 15:23-24).  But what we often overlook is that Paul's occasion for writing is more immediately connected with his journey to Jerusalem where he  will finally deliver this gentile offering. (Romans 15:26-32).  And it apparently weighs heavily on his mind (Romans 15:31).

Read in this light, the theme of Jew and Gentile makes a great deal more sense. Romans is a meditation on Paul's gospel and what he hopes to achieve through his ministry to the gentiles.  In Romans 11:13-14 Paul states

> I am talking to you Gentiles.  Inasmuch as I am the apostle to the
>   Gentiles, I make much of my ministry in the hope that I may somehow
>   arouse my own people to envy and save some of them.

It appears highly likely that Paul saw this arousal as coming from the prophetic fulfillment of a later day worship of God among the Gentiles.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative explanation could just be rooted in practicality.

The pattern had already been established by the Antiochene church in Acts 11:27-30. Agabus predicted an imminent famine and the church in Antioch. There were many famines during Claudius's reign (41-54), the most severe of which occurred in Judea around 46-47.

Because of the imminent threat, the Antiochene church acts quickly to meet these needs. The Judean famine of 46-47 is the most likely referent for the famine that Agabus predicted, *though the church in Antioch would not have been in any better position to assist the main church of Jerusalem*. There is evidence of a severe crop failure in Egypt around A.D. 45-46, though it is not directly documented.  However, the hallmarks of the results of such a failure and famine occurred, including mass people migration, and large spikes in default on debt and taxes in the years immediately following this failure.

It was a common practice for the rich to take responsibility for ensuring the grain supply in times of shortage. Therefore, an expected practice for the Antioch community would have been for the leadership to develop a list of the wealthiest Christians in the city, and call on them for support. However, the church responded as a unified body, not relying upon the most wealthy to aid the church in Jerusalem, effectively placing the responsibility of benefaction upon all Christians, and not just the wealthy.  It should be noted, though, that the response was by ability, of which the wealthy would have had more.

It is not inconceivable that Paul was also taking a collection for a greater need in Jerusalem than in the surrounding communities. It also would have shown solidarity with the main church in Jerusalem. Overall, it seems like the pattern of generosity (especially internally) had been set by the Antiochene church. Helping others is not dictated by how much need there is in your immediate vicinity, but is a multifaceted expression of solidarity and shared faith.

Thus, to address the question of why not just let Jerusalem fend for itself because Paul's church plants had their own needs, perhaps the needs of the Achaean churches were less significant than those of the famine-struck region of Judea. It is important to note that questions of attempting to discern the motivations of people whom we cannot directly ask can lead to the wrong kind of speculation. We can attempt to find reasons and circumstances that may have led to the particular decision, but settling on a definitive response will lead to more arguing than should actually occur.

I personally prefer the above practical reason because it fits the chronology reasonably well and it makes sense to me. I'm also not sure there's any evidence of unmet needs in the Achaean/Macedonian churches.

Winter, Bruce W. "Acts and Food Shortages," in *The Book of Acts in its Graeco-Roman Setting*, ed. David W. J. Gill and Conrad Gempf, 59-78. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1994.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is that it came out of the meeting in Jerusalem described in Galatians 2, where Paul writes:

> and when James and Cephas and John, who were acknowledged pillars, recognized the grace that had been given to me, they gave to Barnabas and me the right hand of fellowship, agreeing that we should go to the Gentiles and they to the circumcised. They asked only one thing, that we remember the poor, which was actually what I was eager to do.

If you read the rest of Galatians 2, Paul had a bit of a falling out with the Jerusalem church, it could be that this made him even more interested in holding up his end of the bargain in an attempt to reconcile.

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that Paul is a Pharisee and well steeped in the OT instructions regarding tithe.
**Given the language of his instruction and the context of it, I perceive that Paul is applying the principle of tithe given in the torah and applying it to the Gentiles.**

I.  SIMILARITIES IN LANGUAGE AND INSTRUCTION BETWEEN PAUL'S INSTRUCTION TO THE GENTILES AND OLD TESTAMENT INSTRUCTIONS TO THE JEWS PERTAINING TO TITHE:

1) The tithes brought to Jerusalem.
2) Tithe for the priest, the orphan, & widow.
   The collection to assist the poor and the saints.
3) The context of Passover, first fruits and Pentecost, times when tithes would be brought from the harvest
4) the phraseology of laying aside or storing up "according to how the Lord has prospered you"

[Exodus 23:14-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=iI%20Chronicles%2031%3A5-6&version=NKJV)
[Exodus 34:18-26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+23&version=NKJV)
[Leviticus 2:11-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%202%3A11-14&version=NKJV)
[Leviticus 23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2023&version=NKJV)
[Numbers 18:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2018%3A21-24&version=NKJV)
[Deuteronomy 12:5-26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2012&version=NKJV)
[Deuteronomy 14:22-29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2014%3A22-29&version=NKJV)
[Deuteronomy 16:9-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2016%3A9-17&version=NKJV)
[Deuteronomy 26:1-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2026%3A1-9&version=NKJV)
[II Chronicles 31:5-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=iI%20Chronicles%2031%3A5-6&version=NKJV) (a little insight into how this "storing up" looked).

It would be natural for Paul to instruct gentile churches likewise to send support to the saints in Jerusalem.  this was the hub for the Apostles.

II.  NEW TESTAMENT CONTEXTUAL CONSIDERATION:

In Acts 20,  we see Paul in a hurry to get to Jerusalem for the day of Pentecost!
In 21:17 He is in Jerusalem (presumably based on Acts 20, for Pentecost).  By chapter 24 he is explains at his hearing that after many years, he had come to bring alms to his nation (Jerusalem-Pentecost).

I Corinthians 16 is not a chronological historical account; it is a letter. None the less, we see Paul's instruction regarding the collection to fall in the context of Passover & Pentecost:

Passover: In chapter 5:7-8 Paul instruct the Corinthians to purge out adultery and keep the Passover feast with the unleavened bread of sincerity and truth. In chapter 11, Paul writes to the Corinthians about keeping the traditions as He delivered them to them. He speaks of the Lord’s supper in the context of Passover, “Therefore when you come together in one place, it is not to eat the Lord's Supper. . . .For I received from the Lord that which I also delivered to you: that the Lord Jesus on the same night in which He was betrayed took bread; (v11-23) (That “same night” was **Passover**).

In chapter 15 & 16 He speaks of delivering to the I Corinthians “that which [He] received from the Lord, that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures, and that He was buried, and that He rose again the third day according to the Scriptures, . . . But now Christ has is risen from the dead, and has become **the first fruits** of those who have fallen asleep” (15:20, 23; 16:15). (the first fruits are waved before the LORD by the priest on day one of counting fifty in the context of seven Sabbaths).

Pentecost: We then see, in chapter 15, verse 8 that Paul wants to see the Corinthians and would even like to spend the winter with them, but he doesn’t wish to see them “now on the way , “**But will tarry in Ephesus until Pentecost!”**

We have traditionally tended to spiritualize Paul’s instruction In I Corinthians about keeping the Passover. Likewise, we have applied I Corinthians chapter 11 to weekly Sunday services with communion; but, in reading the whole of Paul’s letter it is not unlikely that these are in the literal context of Passover Firstfruits and Pentecost as is Paul's instruction regarding the collection!

III.  FURTHER THINGS TO CONSIDER:

I have [reason to believe](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2878/2027) that in the New Covenant instances where *Sabbaths* is plural in the phrase translated "first day of the week," it is referring to the day of firstfruits (day one pertaining to the 7 Sabbaths counting to Pentecost rather than to merely the first day of the week (though it falls on the first day of the week once a year).If that is the case that further contributes to a connection between firstfruits and Paul's incstruction pertaining to the collection.  This increases the likelihood that Paul is applying old Covenant principles of tithe to Gentile believers.

IV.  ADDITIONAL PERSPECTIVE:

Of the 13 or 14 books Paul writes, He speaks of first-fruits only in I Corinthians and Romans, books containing instructions on tithe.  (other than that I find the word only used in James where it occurs once and in Revelation.  The book of Revelation has strong Passover connotations with the Lamb slain and the robes dipped in blood . . . Thus, the usage of the term firstfruits in context of Passover, Pentecost (times firstfruits/tithes were brought to Jerusalem) are noteworthy.

In sum, I see strong correlation between YHWH's instruction to Israel regarding the firstfruits (tithe) and Paul's instruction regarding collections.

Answer (score 0):

Part of Paul's intention that we may undervalue, if we view it as somewhat transcendental, is his desire to increase the praise from the earth to God, who admittedly deserves all praise. Paul lists praise to God as one desired result of this offering (2 Corinthians 9:12-13).

He contrasts the world's religions with the fact that God deserves eternal praise (Romans 1:25). Christ accepted us in order to bring praise to God (Romans 15:7-9) and Paul says we should accept each other for the same reason. In other words, Christ's 'evangelism,' and by extension Paul's, was to change the recalcitrance of the world into proper praise of God.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! We're a little different here, please read our [Site Directives](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) as you ask and answer questions. Thank You!

Comment: You quoted references to illustrate your point, which is  part of our [Site Directives](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). However, you should consider 'quoting the text itself', using the "quote symbol" located at the top of your toolbar and draw your specific inference from the text itself. That way your audience can see the point you're making and compare it with the text you're making it from. Be encouraged! :>)

Answer (score -1):

On Acts 4:32 Says that all the believers were one in heart and mind. No one claimed that any of his possession was his own, but they shared everything they had. Also on verse 34 says that, There were no needy person among them. For from time to time those who owned lands or houses sold them, brought the money from the sales and put it at the apostles' feet, and it was distributed to anyone as he had need that including on verse 36 Barnabas. I think when the amount of believer increased probably they need more income to go forward. then Paul collects the money for their needs.

Answer (score -1):

I asked myself this question...and Googled it:  "Why did Paul say to the church at Corinth (1 Corinthians 16:1-2) - 'Now concerning the collection for the saints, as I have given order to the churches of Galatia, even so do ye.  Upon the first day of the week (Sunday), let EACH OF YOU lay by him (or her) in store (save up) as God has prospered you (over and above His meeting your daily bread needs), that there be no gatherings when I come...(I won't have to take up an offering when I arrive...start setting it aside now)."

The sole answer to that question is found in Romans 15:26 - Paul says to the church at Rome, "For it has pleased them in Macedonia and Achaia (both in Greece -as are the churches of Thessalonica - the present capital of Greece, and Philippi) - to make a certain contribution for the poor saints at Jerusalem."

Now, Paul is speaking in 1 Corinthians.....the church at Corinth about that same offering.

If you trace Paul's footsteps, you would see that Corinth is in Greece.  South of there is Turkey where Galatia and Ephesus are located, and south of there is Israel and Jerusalem in particular.

From Corinth to Jerusalem is a road trip of 1890 miles.  It would take Paul a long time to travel from Corinth to Jerusalem.

When Paul was speaking to the church at Rome (now Romans 15:27-29), he tells them, "It has pleased them (the churches making the contributions) because, indeed, these churches owe the main church at Jerusalem because they have sent us and others out to them to bring the salvation of the Gospel of Christ to them, so they are thrilled at the notion of sharing their financial blessings (prosperity) with the main church at Jerusalem.  So, AFTER I have completed the task and have made sure that they (Jerusalem) have received this contribution, I will go to Spain - but I will stop by here in Rome to visit with you once again."

Answer (score -1):

The many references to famine are true but one thing which seems odd is the slowness of response. Famine relief needs to be fast yet this collection takes a long time and Paul is revisiting churches and waiting at least one winter while organising it and moving the silver(?) with a group of men.

I would suggest that this is as much about sharing capital as sharing income.The Jerusalem church seems to have been a training centre for diaspora Jews from the Day of Pentecost on and they impoverished themselves to support the extra numbers who "devoted themselves to the Apostles teaching". There is also the impact of property confiscation mentioned in Heb 10:34. Imprisonment of members also placed a financial burden on the members outside gaol. Paul states in 2 Cor 8:13 that his aim is "equality" which is a step beyond famine relief and would mean having the resources (land, workshops, tools and materials) to produce an income out of which the Hebrew christians might in future be able to help their Gentile brethren.

Answer (score -2):

On Pentecost the Apostle Peter alluded to the apocalyptic great and terrible Day of the Lord in [Acts 2:17-21](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Acts2:17-21). Later in the same chapter the believers in Jerusalem started divesting themselves of all their worldly goods ([Acts 2:45](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Acts2:45)). For those who were not sincere in their personal sacrifice and who dissembled (Ananias and Sapphira), the discipline was immediate death which caused "great fear" in the Jerusalem church ([Acts 5:11](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Acts5:11)). Thus the believers in Jerusalem disenfranchised themselves of their worldly possessions while there were still yet others who later had their worldly possessions seized from them ([Hebrews 10:34](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Hebrews10:34)). The result was the abject material poverty of these Jewish believers. The Apostle Paul therefore sought to minister to their economic needs through the love of the church from other geographic areas.

Comment: I think any treatment of this subject that should at least raise the issue of famine and other hardships referenced in various places. If if that isn't the direct answer here, you should address why it is not since that is the most commonly cited reason. Until you engage and either confirm or disprove the most commonly cited reasons, this comes off as a very weak argument. Would you be interested in [edit]ing to expland on that point?